# How to create a ms-dos 7.10 program?

Tags: command-prompt, dos

In times to times I see at stores some sellers' programs made in MS-DOS. The program is just black and white, the usage is basically by keyboard. It is not the command prompt because it seems to have a 3D visual, something can be clicked by the mouse, what in cmd doesn't happen.

Below I put two images that show those program I said:

1:

[image: photo 1]

2:

[image: photo 2]

So my questions are:

1. What OS the computer use to operate a program like that.
2. How can I make a program like that, what software I need and what language I need to know?

Comment: Writing MS-Dos programs stopped making sense 23 years ago.  You'll need to visit a museum, the Borland Museum is still open afaik.  Requires a 32-bit version of Windows or a DOS emulator.  Consider to not waste your life on it, there is no point to it.

Comment: I develop software like that a lot time ago using gwbasic or quick basic

Comment: It's not 3D or [2.5D](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2.5D) in graphics mode but a pseudo-3D effect in text mode ([TUI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Text-based_user_interface)). It's still a console application running in the command prompt. You can see it even nowadays in many Linux console applications. It was very common in DOS, with libraries for drawing those TUI objects in Turbo Pascal and Turbo C so you don't have to do it yourself https://forum.lazarus.freepascal.org/index.php?topic=18998.60 http://kriscode.blogspot.com/2018/02/console-vs-gui-application-in-op.html

Comment: `something can be clicked by the mouse, what in cmd doesn't happen` - the Windows Console (sometimes wrongly called `cmd`) does support [mouse input](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/console-input-buffer#span-idmouseeventsspanspan-idmouseeventsspanspan-idmouseeventsspanmouse-events).

Comment: even DOS supports mouse. That's why we can click objects in TUI apps like [NC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Norton_Commander#Background). Some apps like Norton Utilities even use a trick to give you fake graphics mode with ["real" mouse pointer instead of an orange blob](http://www.vcfed.org/forum/showthread.php?11358-The-TUI-(text-mode-GUI)/page2) and even [checkboxes, radio buttons, scroll bars...](https://forum.golem.de/kommentare/applikationen/windows-10-mobile-da-waren-es-nur-noch-13/ich-wuerde-gerne-auf-all-die-hippen-mobile-apps-verzichten/108678,4786845,4786845,read.html) in text mode

Comment: http://toastytech.com/guis/ndtd.html; https://forum.golem.de/kommentare/applikationen/windows-10-mobile-da-waren-es-nur-noch-13/ich-wuerde-gerne-auf-all-die-hippen-mobile-apps-verzichten/108678,4786845,4786845,read.html; https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VGA-compatible_text_mode#Cursor

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The pictures you've shown could be screens of software made by some (old) programming languages like C++, Clipper, GwBasic, QuickBasic, Pascal and a few others. These languages were used before the "magic" of the graphical interface (Windows, MacOs etc) and later got improvements to run graphically, taking many advantages like mouse support and, most important, easier network support.

Clipper made an enormous success at the Brazil of the 90's. Every street business had it's own Clipper soft to help managing.

Some of these programming languages even evolved to use a graphical IDE (Integrated Development Environment), like VisualC++, VisualBasic, Delphi (as the evolution of old Pascal) etc. But then the executables build with them turned to be graphically demanded, i.e.: they began to depend on a graphical user interface to run - and so it was the days when executables didn't need anything to run... just a green phosphorus display and a coarse keyboard with remnants of pizza and ketchup :D

I see by your pictures you live in Brazil. Probably you see yet nowadays old systems with this "DOS" aspect running in some places like video location stores (video locadoras) and car parking stations (estacionamentos). These old soft systems truly require lot less resources than their actual counterparts developed under graphical environment like Windows, but in real they have very poor support for networking (this could mean a printer on a lan too) and runs in "compatibility mode" only, cause our nowadays systems are mainly 64-bits (and they are 32). The compatibility mode can represent problems with memory allocation, can down the performance of your entire environment, can represent risk to your machine, can make your anti-virus spam annoying virus alerts etc.

I would not say "it's useless", but in fact, to be honest - almost useless. They can be useful if you intent to develop something very precise, taylor made, with a taste of vintage computing, for a video location store, (if you own the business) for example, it can be fairly ok. But the efforts can not be fruitful if you have to transform this first system into another one, to make an adaptation, for example, for another store or business. These languages, based on their proper IDE, have very low productivity, no encapsulation, no objects to reuse.

In terms of OS to develop some of these softs, normally you will be tied to your destination platform: if you want to develop this "text-mode" soft to run in a Linux, you will have to program in a Linux machine, cause this will be the environment who will create those specific bitecodes to run only on that platform. If you intent to run your app on a Windows (DOS) machine, you will have to delve into a Windows IDE.

Maybe an investigation could be done, discharging this "text-mode" idea, into the Java platform (I am not talking about applets nor Android), just pure 100% java: it is window enabled, small in terms of kbytes, does not demand DLLs to be installed on destination nor it will make that famous "Registry Mess" every soft do on install; then you can get benefits from an Object Oriented language, already net enabled, almost multi platform (with small changes you can make your basic code run on Win, Mac and Linux), and with a syntax very popular and near from that of C++ but with much automated facilities (avoiding you to get bitten as C++ does) as memory management.

The sad conclusion is: maybe it is worthless to fight against the evolution.

Please, feel free to check my answer as the correct one if you think it was helpful to address your doubts. Thank you.

Comment: Oh, thanks for answer me and help so much me !
You're right, i am from Brazil. Some stores here use programs like that i shown. I got sad to know that these programs have network and compatibility problems :( I like so much this "old" visual.
So, to solve this problem, what tools i need to build a program like that in a modern Oh, thanks for answer me and help so much me !
You're right, i am from Brazil. Some stores use programs like that i shown. I got sad to know that these programs have network and compatibility problems :( I like so much this "old" visual.

Comment: So, what tools i need to build a program like that using moderns environment ? What steps ? Exist something similar with that ?

Comment: There is a website with old tools: http://vetusware.com . I see they have Clipper compiler, but did not registered to confirm if download is active. I would recommend you search for the Clipper language, cause all those success it made probably reflected in a large amount of literature and reference that can be survived until our present days. Yet Clipper was popular too because its low learning curve and alleged "simplicity", and I would complement saying it was one "useful" language, practically speaking, probably those screens you put were from Clipper progs. Keep it up ;) Thank you.

Comment: I spend a time searching for Clipper compiler and its stuff. Looking all answers here i gave up study that language to do something outdated. So i am in a language called "autohotkey", it is little simple and i can make things more real for me because i build the visual part and background on my own. Do you think is it more reliable ?

Oh no, i am from Pernambuco :) If we dont know each other i want this to happen, hahaha, you have a lot of knowing to teach ! Are you into a Project actually?

Answer (score 4):

That is known as a [Text-based User Interface](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Text-based_user_interface) or TUI and most modern operating systems support them. Dos isn't required or recommended to be used for this. You can use the console functions with the Windows API for a windows TUI, or curses or ncurses under Unix-like systems.

Comment: Good to know ! I will lookup for it ! Thanks for the answer !
You have a tutorial or somenthing like that teach how can i use Windows API to got my goal ?

Comment: windows API is irrelevant here. You can use libraries like [tag:ncurses] for that purpose